# What is the difference between python and java == operator

Tags: java, python, string, equals

Can somebody explain to me why Python is able to print the following statement bellow while Java doesn't. I know it's something to do with == in Java and equals() but I don't really understand the difference.

**Python code**

````
str1 = "Pro"
str2 = str1 + ""

if str1 == str2:
   print("the strings are equal")```
````

**Java Code**

```
public class StringEq {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "Pro";
        String str2 = str1 + "";

       if (str1 == str2) {
            System.out.println("The strings are equal");
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Compare it with `.equals()`

Comment: Those operators mean different things in two languages. `==` in Java is equivalent to `is` in Python, i.e. it compares if the two strings point to the same memory location.

Comment: Python != Java , so I don't know what you were expecting.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OP is likely aware of the fact that Java != Python. I think the OP is wondering about *why* there's a semantic difference in the first place when implementing similar behavior would've seemed to be a more logically consistent use of the same syntax. Explaining the difference by saying Java != Python is like explaining a plane crash by saying "well, because gravity" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python `==` is used to compare the content of the objects by overriding the [operator.**eq**(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__eq__) method, `str` class has overridden this in order to compare the content of objects

```
These are the so-called “rich comparison” methods. The correspondence 
between operator symbols and method names is as follows: x<y calls 
x.__lt__(y), x<=y calls x.__le__(y), x==y calls x.__eq__(y), x!=y calls 
x.__ne__(y), x>y calls x.__gt__(y), and x>=y calls x.__ge__(y).
```

But in java `==` operator is used compare the reference of objects [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compare-strings)

> Using the “==” operator for comparing text values is one of the most common mistakes Java beginners make. This is incorrect because “==” only checks the referential equality of two Strings, meaning if they reference the same object or not.

so in java to compare the content of object you have to use `equals` which is overridden in `String` class.

```
if (str1.equals(str2))
```

so java `==` operator is equal to `is` operator in python which compare both references are pointed to same object or not

Comment: Silly question but what's the difference between the reference of an object and content of object?

Comment: hoping you know python, what is the difference between `is` and `==` in python?

Comment: @Adamtoo An exact clone of you could be considered equal to you in terms of value-equality, but would not be equal to you in terms of reference-equality. You may be equal in terms of your genes (your "content"), but you are not the same exact person.

Comment: The class name is `str` in Python.

Comment: So from what I understand is checks for identities and == checks for equality. Since the two strings in java aren't exactly the same as shown in the code, it outputs as False while in Python it does the opposite?

Comment: `Since the two strings in java aren't exactly the same` Is wrong they both are same, but not exactly not pointed to same object it outputs `False` @Adamtoo while in python `==` compares content where both objects have same content

Comment: try `str1.equals(str2)` in java it will print `true` because both of them have same content @Adamtoo

Comment: Ahh right I see now. I'm just slightly confused about the object part, what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3):

Python's `str` class uses value-equality for its `__eq__` method. In Python, classes can override `__eq__` to define how `==` behaves.

Contrast that with Java where `==` always does reference-equality. In Java, `==` will only return `true` if both objects are literally the same object; regardless of their content. Java's `==` is more comparable to Python's `is` operator.

A better comparison, as noted in the comments, would be to compare these:

```
"a".equals("a")  // Java

"a" == "a"  # Python
```

Java's `String` class has its `equals` do a value equality instead of of reference equality.

Comment: Yes, Java `==` is more like Python `is`

Answer (score 1):

It explains it well [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/):

And here is a quote from that site:
"We can use == operators for reference comparison (address comparison) and .equals() method for content comparison. In simple words, == checks if both objects point to the same memory location whereas .equals() evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects."